# Keep getting out of bounds exception, don't know why?

Tags: unix, command-line

I'm making a 3 dimensional tic tac toe game. The game is complete and works fine, however, the assignment demands that (for testing game situations) the program take in a file of integers that places pieces on the game board. It takes in the file from the Unix command line.

However, the game is supposed to run from start if no file is entered in command line. I'm getting an out of bounds exception and don't know why for the life of me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Portion of code for getting file and storing the integers:

```
public class Test {
    static int board[][][] = new int[4][4][4];
    static boolean ComputerMoved = false;
    static int[] sums = new int[76];
    static int n = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        //Method purpose is to look and see if there is a startup file given to
        //initally setup the board. If not, plays an empty board and prompts the
        //user for the first move.

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(args[0]));

           if (args.length > 0) {
                int size = scan.nextInt();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    int level = scan.nextInt();
                    int row = scan.nextInt();
                    int column = scan.nextInt();
                    int value = scan.nextInt();

                    level = level % 4;
                    row = row % 4;
                    column = column % 4;

                    board[level][row][column] = value;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It appears that the out of bounds exception is coming not from your array, but rather your scanner. Could it be possible you don't have "enough" numbers to scan?

Comment: I see what I did wrong. I was using the first position in the array before checking the length. Thanks!